# JAVA-Is it possible to make a backup of a database which is on phpmyAdmin using java code?

Tags: java, database, netbeans, phpmyadmin

I need to make a backup of a certian database (including tables and data on tables) which is stored on phpmyAdmin using java code. Any help? Thanks in advance

Comment: I found, you need to use something called mysqldump but if its MySql DB stored on the pc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. phpMyAdmin is used to maintain MySQL Databases via a Web-Browser, implemented in PHP (c.f. https://www.phpmyadmin.net/).
2. If you want to access a MySQL DB from Java you can try to use JDBC (https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/).

If you really, really want to do your backup via phpMyAdmin you could try to write a Selenium-Test testing your phpMyAdmin instance (http://www.seleniumhq.org/). But I guess, there are easier ways to get the job done.

Comment: I already done the database on phpmyadmin, and used JDBC and it works correcly. Now i just need to add code which creates an export of the databse stored on phpmyadmin (for exampl .msql file ).

Comment: Maybe you should google your problem. I found this: https://coderanch.com/t/480353/databases/MySql-DB-backup-java

Comment: I tried it but didn't worked. I now made a method that backup the data on tables to an Excel file. Not as I wanted it but better than nothing :)